# Notch filters and harmonic noise in matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, noise

So basically, my problem is that I have a speech signal in .wav format that is corrupted by a harmonic noise source at some frequency. My goal is to identify the frequency at which this noise occurs, and use a notch filter to remove said noise. So far, I have read the speech signal into matlab using:

```
[data, Fs] = wavread('signal.wav');
```

My question is how can I identify the frequency at which the harmonic noise is occurring, and once I've done that, how can I go about implementing a notch filter at that frequency?

NOTE: I do not have access to the iirnotch() command or fdesign.notch() due to the version of MATLAB I am currently using (2010).

Answer (score 2):

The general procedure would be to analyse the spectrum, to identify the frequency in question, then design a filter around that frequency. For most real applications it's all a bit woolly: the frequencies move around and there's no easy way to distinguish noise from signal, so you have to use clever techniques and a bit of guesswork. However if you know you have a monotonic corruption then, yes, an FFT and a notch filter will probably do the trick.

You can analyse the signal with `fft` and design a filter with, among others, `fir1`, which I believe is part of the signal processing toolbox. If you don't have the signal processing toolbox you can do it 'by hand', as in transform to the frequency domain, remove the frequency(ies) you don't want (by zeroing the relevant elements of the frequency vector) and transform back to time domain. There's a tutorial on exactly that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317054/Simple-FFT-and-Filtering-Tutorial-with-Matlab).

The `fft` and `fir1` functions are well documented: search the Mathworks site to get code examples to get you up and running.

Answer (score 1):

To add to/ammend xenoclast's answer, filtering in the frequency domain may or may not work for you. There are many thorny issues with filtering in the frequency domain, some of which are covered here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/why-eq-is-done-in-time-domain.html

One additional issue is that if you try to process your entire file at once, the "width" or Q of the filters will depend on the length of your file. This might work out for you, or it might not. If you have many files of different lengths, don't expect similar results this way.

To design your own IIR notch filter, you could use the [RBJ audio filter cookbook](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt). If you need help, I wrote up a tutorial here:

http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html

My tutorial uses bell/peaking filter, but it's easy to follow that and then replace it with a notch filter from RBJ.

One final note: assuming this is actually an audio signal in your .wav file, you can also use your ears to find and fix the problem frequencies:

- Open the file in an audio editing program that lets you adjust filter settings in real-time (I am not sure if audacity lets you do this, but probably).
- Use a "boost" or "parametric" filter set to a high gain and sweep the frequency setting until you hear the noise accentuated the most.
- replace the boost filter with a notch filter of the same frequency. You may need to tweak the width to trade off noise elimination vs. signal preservation.
- repete as needed (due to the many harmonics).
- save the resulting file.

Of course, some audio editing apps have built-in harmonic noise reduction features that work especially well for 50/60 Hz noise.